# Glob() filesearch, question

Tags: php, file, search, glob

a little question. I have this code, which is works perfect for files, but If am trying search on a directory name, the result is blank. How I can fix that?

```
<?php
function listdirs($dir,$search)
{
    static $alldirs = array();
    $dirs = glob($dir."*");
    foreach ($dirs as $d){
        if(is_file($d)){
            $filename = pathinfo($d);
            if(eregi($search,$filename['filename'])){   
                print  "<a href=http://someurl.com/" . $d .">". $d . "</a><br/>";
            }
        }else{
            listdirs($d."/",$search);
        }
    }
}
$path = "somedir/";
$search= "test";
listdirs($path,$search);
?>
```

somedir/test/

result: blank (I want: /somedir/test/)

somedir/test/test.txt

result: OK

I want to search also in the directory names, how I can do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to search for a directory, you're going to have to change the `if(is_file($d))` block.  Right now, you're having it simply call `listdirs` again when it encounters a directory... but this also means you'll never see a `print` with a link to said directory.

I suggest doing something like this in the `foreach` instead:

```
    $filename = basename($d);
    if(eregi($search,$filename)){   
        print  "<a href=http://someurl.com/" . $d .">". $d . "</a><br/>";
    }
    if(is_dir($d)){
        listdirs($d."/",$search);
    }
```

Comment: Another litte question, is this code safe? Users can't list the server files? Only what I get from users is the $search variable.

Comment: @Peter: It *should* be safe, because of the `basename` call.  However, I've never tried it before, so I can't say for certain that they can't break out of it using specially encoded characters.

Answer (score 0):

Your script is working fine. I think the webserver user does not have permissions to the given directory.

Comment: In that case how is possible this?

Searching for "two"

one/two/ (directory structure)

result: blank (I want: /one/two/)

Searching for file "test" or "test.txt" is working fine.

one/two/test.txt

result: OK (result: one/two/test.txt)

File search is working ok, but any of the directory search not. I think it is not a premission problem.